# Ports USB not working

Tags: usb

[image: picture 3][image: picture 2][image: picture 1]I have Ubuntu 18.04.1. LTS installed on my laptop.
Today i installed **USB guard 0.7.2+ds-1** in order to protect one of my USB sticks. USB guard program is available from **Ubuntu software** and from there you can download it for free. This program is not working properly and i uninstalled it.
But now i have problems with my USB ports, keyboard, mouse and other devices are not working because **USB guard program blocked all three USB ports**. How to activate USB ports?

[image: picture 4]

Answer (score 2):

That particular tool is designed to prevent access to USB *ports* rather than USB sticks. If you would like to protect a USB stick, encryption is really the best option.

In order to regain access to your USB ports, you'll need to follow a number of steps, some of which you may have done already.

The following steps will all be done through Terminal, as it's just faster this way:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Check if you have a `/etc/usbguard/rules.conf` file:

   ```
   ll /etc/usbguard
   ```

   If you see a message like `ls: cannot access '/etc/usbguard': No such file or directory`, then move on to the next step. If you *do* have this directory, then modify the `rules.conf` file like this:

   ```
   sudo echo "allow id *:*" > /etc/usbguard/rules.conf
   sudo sed -i 's/PresentDevicePolicy=apply-policy/PresentDevicePolicy=allow/' /etc/usbguard/usbguard-daemon.conf
   sudo reboot
   ```

   ***Note:** Rebooting the machine is rather important, so do not skip this step.*
2. The next step is to ensure you do not have any of the `usbguard` services running, as these things are pernicious:

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop usbguard.service
   sudo systemctl disable usbguard.service
   sudo systemctl stop usbguard-dbus.service
   sudo systemctl disable usbguard-dbus.service
   ```

   If all of these result in errors, then you do not have the `usbguard` services running.
3. Now we get to scrub `usbguard` from the system as much as possible:

   ```
   sudo apt remove usbguard -y
   sudo apt purge usbguard -y
   ```
4. Scrub the `/etc/usbguard` directory from your system:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf /etc/usbguard/
   ```
5. Reboot the system one last time

Once this is done, you *should* have access to your USB ports again.

Comment: Dear Matigo, thank you very much for your advice, it helped me to resolve my issue with USBguard virus alike app. At the beginning in Terminal i received responses as ,,command not found,, or ,,permission denied,, but finally every thing went good with sudo apt remove usbguard -y  But i do not want to explain a lot, here i am sending you picture of the outmut from Terminal. Because i did not have option to copy paste from keyboard so i used screen capture.

Comment: Dear Matigo, as i see here is no option to share pictures and if you want i can send it to you on mail or other places. Just send me where to send it.

Comment: Images can be added to the question. You can edit the original and add information at any time.

Comment: Hi Matigo, i just uploaded 4 pictures, hoping you will find the right order. Thanks for your advice again :)

Comment: Matigo; Would you answer my new question i posted? Here: A few days ago I removed a USB stick before clicking on Safely remove and since then the USB stick is not recognizable to Ubuntu also on Windows xp or Android on mobile phone. I have tried to reboot Ubuntu with USB attached on a Laptop but no results. How to make USB recognizable to UBUNTU 18.04.1 LTS ?